# How do I get the burn time for a fuel source?

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

I'm using `Material.{something}.isFuel()` to get if an item is a fuel source, but how do I get what the burn time for that fuel source is...?

Comment: Not sure if bukkit will allow, but `TileEntityFurnace.getItemBurnTime(stack)` is how I've done it in Forge and it's a vanilla method.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is nothing such.
But you could create an Enum containing the fuel info as the following spigot article shows:

```java
public enum Fuel {
    LAVA_BUCKET(Material.LAVA_BUCKET, 20000),
    COAL_BLOCK(Material.COAL_BLOCK, 16000),
    BLAZE_ROD(Material.BLAZE_ROD, 2400)
    // ...

    private Material type;
    private int burntime;

    public Fuel(Material type, int burntime) {
        this.type = type;
        this.burntime = burntime;
    }

    public int getBurnTime() {
        return burntime;
    }
}
```

[Link to the Spigot article](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/getting-total-fuel-time-in-a-furnace.334433/#post-3118523)